# Area of Portions (Divisions) of a Circle

Tags: geometry, area

Let $ABCD$ be a square of side length 4. Let $M$ be on side $\overline{BC}$ such that $CM = 1$, and let $N$ be on side $\overline{AD}$ such that $DN = 1$. We draw the quarter-circle centered at $A$.

[image]

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the areas of the shaded regions, as shown. Find $x - y$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the lower white area between x and y as z. Now x-y = (x+z)-(y+z) = (area of quarter circle) - (area of rectangle MNDC)